# Kinds of trips and their verbs

Tags: expression-choice, phrasal-verbs, syntactic-analysis

There is an exercise in a book I use which asks students to put the words for the kinds of trips in a chart, under three columns: **Go**, **Take** and **Go on a/an**. The problem is that after students do it, the book starts showing the verbs with different trip situations. Example: "going on a saffari" is later seen as "taking a saffari trip", and "taking a city tour" is also displayed as "going on a city tour". Are there any rules in English that specify the verbs that go with kinds of trips, like **cruise**, **road trip**, **pilgrimage** etc. ?

Comment: _Go_ and _take_ are related; _take_ is the causative of _go_ (similarly, _bring_ is the causative of _come_). Basically, if you take something or someone, they go with you; if you bring them, they come with you. So there are lots of idiomatic constructions that work with either light verb. _He brought it to fruition = It came to fruition; He took it to a higher level = It went to a higher level._ As for _go on a_, that's only for count nouns referring to individual instances of travel excursions of a standard kind: _hike, jaunt, boat/car/plane/horse ride,_ etc.

Comment: @John Lawler And to think that I was about to label this as 'too general'.

Comment: The problem with John Lawler's comments is that they often make it impossible for any self-respecting user to offer an answer.

Comment: Actually, there are very few "restrictions".  You can even "cruse" in a car.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the swamp of grammar, to me this is a matter of usage. A native would naturally say, 'I'm going on a cruise (safari, tour, etc.). The thing is that we go on 'trips' organized for us where we are 'captive' of the 'organizers'. We take trips that we ourselves organize. e.g., I'm taking a trip to Atlanta (the person is driving. Just because one is flying to Atlanta or taking a bus doesn't qualify as 'organized' by another). The important thing is the person bought a ticket solely for travel. 'going on a trip' implies an import to the travel beyond just getting to a place. There's a grander purpose for traveling. What's my authority for this? Experience and common sense--the first victims of over-analysis of grammar.